# Why is openjdk-8 not installed well?

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk

I installed `openjdk-8-jdk`, but at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`, there is only `bin`, `include`, `lib`, `man`.

Also, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin` has just 2 files (`appletviewer`, `jconsole`).

So I've removed it and then re-installed it, but it doesn't work.

How do I get Java to install correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "installed well"? What happens when you just run `java` or `javac`? Why are you trying to look in the installation directory?

Comment: Do you want to download TLanuncher ,If so read the Readme file which comes after extracting, it has information to download Java 8

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk  
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk
```